# I am run the project in Qt at that time i am getting this error

Tags: android, qt

I am new to qt. i have build one project in Android Qt 5.15.2 Clang Multi-Abi and Desktop Qt 515.2 MSVC2019 32bit when I try to run this project in desktop it is run successfully. but when I try to run with android device it is give this error.

```
error: The deployment device "Redmi Note 7S" does not support the architectures used by the kit.
The kit supports "armeabi-v7a", but the device uses "".
```

Please help. how can i solve this error ?

and one more question is how can i check the target android SDK version of this project ? means on which SDK version use this project.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this error

```
error: The deployment device "Redmi Note 7S" does not support the architectures used by the kit.
The kit supports "armeabi-v7a", but the device uses "".
```

you need to turn **OFF** the **USB debugging** mode from your mobile once and again turn **ON** it.

For this question

> how can i check the target android SDK version of this project ? means
> on which SDK version use this project.

You need to go into the project tab in Qt from left pane. then select your android kit. then go into the build tab. into the build tab click on the **Details** of the **Build Android APK**. and in this there is one field **Android build platform SDK:** in this field you can see the SDK API Version.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, on Qt Creator 11.0.1, to solve this error, I need to disconnect the phone, delete the device then connect the phone back in.

The steps are like this

1. Disconnect the phone
2. On the left pane, go to Projects > Manage Kits on the upper left
3. Choose Devices, select the disconnected device, click Remove on the right side
4. Then connect the phone back in

I think the error happens because QT Creator only init the device information once. If the first time there are error when reading device information, it will stay that way. We need to delete the device and reconnect to update the information